# UIToolbar and other views

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar

I know how to add a UIToolbar, which I'm doing in rootviewcontroller.m:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

However, when I navigate to other views, the toolbar stays up, which is ok, but how do I access it to hide/show it?

Inside rootviewcontroller I would use this:

```
toolbar.hidden = NO;
```

But I can't seem to find a way to do this outside of rootviewcontroller.m

Can you please show me an example of hiding it from another class?

Answer (score 3):

There are two options;

1) Add a property to your controller so external classes can access to the toolbar object.

2) Add a function to your root view controller that can be used to toddle the toolbar.

I would recommend #2 since it restricts what external classes can do.

E.g.

```
-(void) hideToolbar:(BOOL)hidden
{
  toolbar.hidden = hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you shouldn't be adding it to `self.navigationController.view`; you should be adding it to `self.view`.  Correcting that should fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the following line during the initialisation of the View Controllers for which you don't want the bar to appear.

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

F.

Answer (score -1):

Andrew Grant's answer is what you're looking for.  However, you should rename the method to

```
-(void) isToolbarHidden:(BOOL)hidden {
    toolbar.hidden = hidden;
```

}

It makes more sense that way when looking at the code.

Comment: isToolbarHidden, and yet it doesn't return anything but in fact changes the hidden value? Perhaps setToolbarHidden...